# Why isn't my upload script writing files to the given path?

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I'm trying to upload image to different directory's by category.. i have everything else set but when i try to upload the image it comes to images/... and not to lets say images/boxes/.... why with value of the $category "boxes"? where i do wrong ?
this is an example of the script tht im trying to use .. can somebody help me with that ?

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET product_name='$product_name', price='$price', details='$details', category='$category', subcategory='$subcategory' WHERE id='$pid'");
if ($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") {
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../images/$newname");
}
header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
exit(); }
```

Comment: Please change your question title to something informative

Comment: Have a look at some other questions on Stack Overflow, and read the FAQs - then compare your question with what we expect here. Please give the question a meaningful title. Please only show code that's relevant to the problem - if your problem is with file naming, why do we need to see all the SQL stuff?

Comment: i do post everything just to be more informative thats all

Comment: Thanks will for correcting my title

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the directory first using "mkdir"?

Comment: but i have directory's created already why do i need to recreate them ?

Comment: Do you have the $newname folder created inside the "images" though?

Comment: sure i have all category folders inside image folder Box Mart and Other ... but whatever i do images goes just ot ../images/ and thats all

Answer (score 0):

Your file is uploaded to `images/...` as you are specifying it in your `move_uploaded_file`

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../images/$newname");
```

If you want it to go to the `category` folder like `images/boxes/...` your need to include the `category` in the `move_uploaded_file` `string $destination`

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../images/$category/$newname");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i already tryed this and photos goes to ../images/ and not to $catogory specification.. i dont understand this ..that's the strange i mean..even if i speficy move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../images/$category/$newname"); its return same result

Answer (score 0):

I just finished solving this problem myself. I'm actually using the EXACT same code that you are using. Thats how I came about finding you.

The resolution I came to implement was to change the read write permissions through my servers Control Panel. Allow read/write/execute to */store* folder in main root direcrory.

Hope this helps.... a year later